# For a single CDH (Hadoop) cluster installation, which host should I use?

Tags: linux, hadoop, cloudera

I started with a Windows 7 computer, and set up an Ubuntu Linux virtual machine `which I run using VirtualBox`. `The Cloudera Manager Free Edition version 4` has been executed, and I have been following the prompts on `localhost:7180`.

I am now stuck when the prompt asks me to "Specify hosts for your CDH cluster installation." Can I install all of the Hadoop components, as well as run them, in the linux virtual machine alone?

Please help point me in the right direction in which host I should specify.

Comment: is this question answered? I am stuck at the same place. Its keep showing me "Could not connect to host".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run cdh in a linux virtual machine alone. You could do it using "standalone" or "pseudo distributed" modes. IMHO, the most effective method for doing it is to use the "pseudo distributed" mode.

In this case, there are multiple java-virtual-machines (JVM) running, so they simulated as they were a cluster with multiples nodes (each thread simulated to be a cluster node).

Cloudera has documented how to get deployed as "pseudo distributed":

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/cdh_qs_cdh5_pseudo.html

Note: 3 ways for deploying cdh:

1. standalone: using a machine alone, with a unique jvm
2. pseudo-distributed: using a machine alone, but several jvm's, so
   simulated to be a cluster
3. distributed: using a cluster, so several
   nodes with different purposes (workers, namenode, etc).

Answer (score 0):

you can specify hostname of your machine. it will install everything on your machine only.